# Convert number to a binary code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binary, numbers

What function or method converts number (2354) to binary code (001011001010)?
Thanks

Comment: Unclear how you get the zeroes at the start of your binary version. Also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
number= 2345
binary = number.toString(2)
console.log(binary)
```

the result of this code is : 100100101001

btw : 001011001010 in binary is equal to 714 in decimal ;)
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have been asked many times before. [We mark them as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) so all the good and up-to-date content stays in one place.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I've found the answer. Not good start for me in asking.
Now trying to ask "is any analog of jquery.bacstretch in react" but I can't because of questions limit(